# Spring security : Custom authentication provider not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using custom authentication provider which implements "AuthenticationProvider". In SecurityConfig i am using following configs.

```
http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/login/authenticateUser").permitAll()
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
```

The above configuration does not call custom authentication provider for login API but for other API's the custom authetication provider is not being called which is throwing forbidden error.

```
@Autowired
private CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);          
}
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/login/authenticateUser").permitAll()
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();      
}
```

Custom authentication provider:

```
@Component
```

public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

```
static Map<String, UserDetails> userSessionList = new HashMap<String, UserDetails>();

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

    String userName = authentication.getName();
    String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString().split(";")[0];

    if (checkUserNameAndPassword(userName, password)) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
        grantedAuths.add(() -> {
            return "AUTH_USER";
        });
        Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userName, password, grantedAuths);
        return auth;
    } else {
        throw new AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException("Invalid Credentials!");
    }
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    //return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
    return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
}
```

Please help me to solve this issue. Custom authentication provider should be called for all the requests except login controller.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Your authentication provider is always call, if you choose an authentication with an `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`. What authentication do you use?

Comment: I use in memory UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication technique. In the above configuration custom authentication provider is not being called instead it is throwing forbidden error without reaching custom authentication provider

Comment: What does *I use in memory UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication technique*? That's not standard Spring Security. Show your code for that authentication.